# Absorbing at Each point means Open?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

In a topological vector space, it seems that open sets have the property that they are absorbing at each of their points, since $(\alpha,x)\to \alpha x$ is continuous.

I am wondering if the converse is true. Is it correct that a set that is absorbing at each of its points is open?

- Absorbing: a set $S$ is absorbing in a vector space $X$ if for every $x \in X$ there exist a $r \geq 0$, s.t. $\forall \;|\alpha|>r,\; x \in \alpha S $.
- Absorbing at $x_0$: $S$ is absorbing at $x_0$ if $S-x_0$ is absorbing.

Comment: What does "absorbing" mean here?

Comment: Absorbing, defined: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_set

Comment: What do you mean by absorbing "at each point"?

Comment: Still not clear what "absorbing at each of their points" means. Presumably, it means absorbing when translating each point to zero.

Comment: My guess is that it means: $S$ is absorbing at $x$ if $S-x$ is absorbing.

Comment: Short (unsatisfying) answer: No. 
Just put the indiscrete topology on any vector space. Absorbing sets need not be the whole space.

Comment: @Amudhan: I guess that unsatisfyingness is why many authors assume $T_1$ as part of the definition of topological vector space.

Comment: Thank you for your discussions. I have edited it and added the definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, in an infinite dimensional Banach space, open balls are not open in the weak topology.

Comment: Jonas, thank you very much for your answer! I guess you meant that absorbing is a purely algebraic property. Open balls in a Banach space are absorbing regardless of the topology, but open balls are not open in weak topology. Did I got it?

Comment: Could you please give me a reference about open balls being not open in weak topology? Thank you!

Comment: @Zack: You're welcome.  To your first comment: Yes. To your second: First a comment that the same would be true of any TVS topology that is strictly coarser than the norm topology.  The reason is that if open balls were open, so would be unions of them, hence every norm-open set would be.  (And if even one open ball were open, all of them would be, because they are homeomorphic in a TVS topology.)  But this leaves at least the question of how to prove that the weak topology is strictly coarser than the norm topology on an infinite dimensional vector space. (to be continued)

Comment: @Zack: You can see Davide Giraudo prove twice that weakly open sets are unbounded: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439928/show-that-b-it-is-unbounded, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223221/if-x-is-infinite-dimensional-all-open-sets-in-the-sigmax-x-ast-topolo?rq=1

Comment: Jonas, I read the first link, and it is quite clear! Thanks a lot!